# PHP->bash->python Output

Tags: php, python-3.x, bash

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
passthru("bash /var/www/html/init.sh 2>&1",$pass_result);
echo $pass_result; 
?>
```

I am unable to get the python result at PHP level.
The python script print("string") to the bash script and if I do

```
#!/bin/sh
START=$(python3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py)
echo "${START}"
```

This works if I run the bash script, it outputs the string on the terminal
but if I call it from the PHP, it finishes immediately with this
error:

```
#PHP OUTPUT
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: 
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.0) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported " Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py", line 34, in driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__ super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog", 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__ self.service.start() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start self.assert_process_still_running() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1 0
```

If I put a while and a for the behavior becomes weird

```
#!/bin/sh
START=python3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py &
BACK_PID=$!
while kill -0 $BACK_PID ; do
        for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do
            sleep 5
            echo "WTF" $i
        done
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
done
```

with this code the bash script will get the output of the python string at around 8 iterations of the for loop running it directly on the terminal and this is the only way I got PHP to wait for the end of the bash script, and it returns all
9 WTFs but no python string, I can't understand why it is not reaching the PHP.

```
#PHP OUTPUT
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.0) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported " Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py", line 34, in driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__ super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog", 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__ self.service.start() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start self.assert_process_still_running() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1 WTF 0 WTF 1 WTF 2 WTF 3 WTF 4 WTF 5 WTF 6 WTF 7 WTF 8 WTF 9 /var/www/html/init.sh: line 4: kill: (11275) - No such process 0
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with missing environment variables when it's launched from PHP? You could try to print them and compare them with the ones you have when you launch it from your shell console.

Comment: you mean the variables for the python script? I set them to a fixed value inside the python script for testing purposes.